# Typecasting in Rails finder methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one column named bill_date with data type as timestamp without time zone.

Now i want to search a record with the bill_date. The user will enter date as like 2012-12-09.

I want to use Bill.find_by_bill_date(2012-12-09).

The above one will not give result. Because We have to do typecasting. Please give me some suggestions. I don't want to use where clause or conditions. I want to use find_by only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a method to your Bill class like this:

```
def self.find_by_bill_date(date)
  where("DATE(bill_date) = DATE(?)", date).first
end
```

I know you said you didn't want to use where clauses, but the dynamic finder methods (find_by_*) do the exact same thing, anyway.

Comment: Hi Nick, It's not working. Because in the database the value is "2012-12-09 13:08:45.211646". If we search with "2012-12-09". it wont give result. If we do typecast to date then it will work. Please give idea to do typecast in find_by method.

Comment: is there any way to do type casting in the find_by_bill_date line itself. without creating separate method?

Comment: without using where clause also.

Comment: No. find_by methods are there as helpers for a specific purpose. If you need them to do anything more complex, you need to override them or create your own method. This is what programming is all about. There isn't always going to be method to do exactly what you want. Sometimes (most of the time) you have to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to put a Date.today into a timestamp field . In case you'd like to use it as it is now , better put Time.now instead of Date.today , or change the column to a date .

EDIT : on a type cast :

```
>> h.published_at_before_type_cast
=> "2012-11-15 19:11:15.517923"
```

Comment: Hi, if we type cast the bill_date column as date data type then it will work.

Comment: any idea to do type casting in find_by method??

Comment: I am not able to open that link. Please give me any other Link.

Comment: [Railscast on time zones:](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=asciicast)